# Simple script to ping PCs, output table - what's wrong?

Tags: powershell

I was trying to write a simple script to ping a list of computers, and output the result in a table. I ended up doing this, which works fine:

```
Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Materials,OU=MMC Computers,OU=REI,DC=REIDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -filter * | select -expand name | % {
    $output = New-Object PSObject
    $output | Add-Member NoteProperty "Computer name"($_)
    $output | Add-Member NoteProperty "Ping result"("$($(Test-Connection $_ -count 1 -quiet).ToString())")
    write $output }
```

However, I'd like to understand why my first two attempts didn't work, so that I can avoid making the same mistakes later. Here they are:

**Script 1: *See edit below***

```
Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Materials,OU=MMC Computers,OU=REI,DC=REIDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -filter * | 
select -expand name | % { $computer = $_; $obj = "" | 
select @{Name="Computer";Expression="$computer"},`
@{Name="Pingable";Expression="$($(Test-Connection $computer -count 1 -quiet).ToString())"} 
$obj }
```

**Output 1:**

```
Computer                                 Pingable
-----—                                   -----—
```

*Note:* Under the table headers, this script actually prints one blank line for each computer I'm pinging.

**Script 2:**

```
$table = @{Expression={$_};Label="Computer"},@{Expression={"$($(Test-Connection $_ -count 1 -quiet).ToString())"};Label="Pingable"}
Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Materials,OU=MMC Computers,OU=REI,DC=REIDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -filter * | select -expand name | format-table $table
```

**Output 2:**

```
mickeymouse
goofy
minnie
pluto
frank
```

This one doesn't even output a table...it just prints one computer name per line.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain what's going wrong in these two attempts. Thanks!

**Edit:** Got Script 1 to work.

```
Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Materials,OU=MMC Computers,OU=REI,DC=REIDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -filter * | 
select @{Name="Computer";Expression={$_.Name}},@{Name="Pingable";Expression={"$($(Test-Connection $_.Name -count 1 -quiet).ToString())"}};
```

Still curious about Script 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you are using the `-ExpandProperty` of `Select-Object` which effectively strips the data from the object and outputs an array of strings which `format-table` then outputs as a list.

See this example:

```
#First create the array of objects
$rawData = @( @{"Name"="First Obj"; "OtherParam"=1;}, @{"Name"="Second Obj"; "OtherParam"=2;})
$objects = $rawData | %{new-object -type psobject -prop $_}

#Just output the objects
$objects | format-table
```

*Output:*

```
Name                              OtherParam
----                              ---------- 
First Obj                                  1 
Second Obj                                 2
```

Now select the name property, this gives an array of objects with just a single property "name"

```
$objects | select name | format-table
```

*Output:*

```
Name
----
First Obj
Second Obj
```

Expand the name property, this gives an array of strings that format table just lists with no heading:

```
$objects | select -expand name | format-table
```

*Output:*

```
First Obj
Second Obj
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation! Based on your feedback, I wrote this which works:     

`$table = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Computer"},@{Expression={"$($(Test-Connection $_.Name -count 1 -quiet).ToString())"};Label="Pingable"};

Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Materials,OU=MMC Computers,OU=REI,DC=REIDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -filter * | format-table $table`